# How to access Sinatra custom settings from Service

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to access custom settings defined in my Sinatra application from a service but I am not able to do it.

**application.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/config_file'

class Application < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::ConfigFile
  config_file 'environment/config.yml'

  set :custom_setting_one, 'some_value'
  ...
  ...
end
```

**config.yml**

```
custom_setting_two: some_other_value
```

**my_service.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'

Class MyService
  def do_something
    Sinatra::Application.settings.custom_setting_one # This throws exception
    Sinatra::Application.settings.custom_setting_two # This throws exception
  end
end
```

**exception:**

```
undefined method `custom_setting_one' for Sinatra::Application:Class
```

I can not access either of the configuration variables from the service but I can in the **application.rb** file.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I’m assuming where you have `Class` instead of `class` is just a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re trying to access the settings in `Sinatra::Application`, but you have defined them on your own `Application` class. If you change

```
Sinatra::Application.settings.custom_setting_one
```

to

```
Application.settings.custom_setting_one
```

it should work as you expect. It might be worth to change the name of your application class to something other than `Application`, to avoid confusion like this.

Finally, since you are using the [modular style](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps) you should probably use `require 'sinatra/base'` rather than `require 'sinatra'`.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you very much and I will take your recommendation.